# How to inject $axios into Pinia store SSR

Tags: axios, quasar-framework

I'm trying to inject my `axios` instance into the store so that I'm able to login into the app but unfortunately I'm being unable to. I have the followed boot file

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import axios from 'axios';
import type {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
import type { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

export type WrappedResponse = { response?: AxiosResponse };

export const isError = (e: WrappedResponse, statusCode: StatusCodes) =>
  e.response && e.response.status === statusCode;

export default boot(({ app, store }) => {
  const api = axios.create({ baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL });

  app.provide('axios', api);
  store.$axios = api;
});
```

Then on my store I have:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAppStore = defineStore('app', {
  state: () => ({
  }),
  getters: {
  },
  actions: {
    async login() {
      console.log(this.$axios);
      console.log('Logging in from store');
    }
  },
});
```

Whenever login is called it prints undefined. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to create a [Pinia plugin](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html):

```js
export default boot(({ app, store }) => {
  const api = axios.create({ baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL });

  app.provide('axios', api);
  store.use(() => ({ api })); // 
});
```

Comment: Note it'll only work if `store.use(...)` is called before `appStore = useAppStore()`. Execution order matters! See last sentence of this: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#introduction